# subprocess problem with phpmentor/workflower

Tags: php, workflow, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to draw a bpmn diagram with subprocess and then run it in php workflow. My problem is that the subprocess tag is not detected by the phpmentor workflow. Does anyone know why it happens??

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/phpmentors-jp/workflower/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#workflow-elements-supported-by-workflower  phpmentor workflow doe snot support subprocesses.